# Assessing rater bias where one rater has given one very high rating and the remainder very low ratings

Tags: reliability, agreement-statistics, bias

What is a good statistical test to check if there is a bias in judging in a situation that there is one judge that gave extreme scores (high score for one of the contestant and very low scores on the rest of the contestants)?  Here is the actual data in the contest:

```
                 contestant 1      contestant 2     contestant 3    contestant 4
judge 1            83.03               96.5             88.5           90.5
judge 2            67.15               89.9             85.36          89.85
judge 3            72.05               84.6             78.95          85
judge 4            86.95               93.3             88             94.1
judge 5            44                  65.15            52.45          96.05
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: This isn't a "test" per se, but a boxplot (or even scatter plot) might be useful for visualizing the distribution of scores.

Comment: I've tried to make the question title reflect the rather specific form of bias that you are interested in. Feel free to modify if I have misconstrued.

Answer (score 4):

#### Overview

Usually when I think of multiple raters assessing multiple objects, I think of "bias" as a mean difference in expected rating of a particular judge from the mean of a hypothetical population of judges.
This is a rather statistical definition of bias, which does not necessarily correspond to everyday definitions of bias, which would presumably also include the notion of failure to impartially apply relevant standards.

#### Basic ideas

Bearing in mind that there is probably an established literature on this, these are the ideas that came to my mind:

- Compare **mean** rating of each judge

  - is a given judge harsher or more lenient on average?
- Compare **standard deviation** or variance of each judge

  - is the judge differentiating to the extent that is expected or in ways consistent with other judges?
- For each judge, **correlate** that judge's ratings with the mean of all other judges, and use the correlation as an index of the validity of that judge's ratings

  - is the judge identifying quality in the same way as other judges?
- Build a model predicting ratings for contestant i by judge j and record the **residuals**; large absolute residuals could be excluded from some overall rating. The model could be as simple as an ANOVA predicting response for contestant i by judge j using just the main effects (no interaction effects).

  - is a judge responding in an uncharacteristic manner for a particular contestant?

The **mean** approach is what I think of as bias.
The **residuals** approach will capture what you are interested in.

#### Basic implementation in R

I hacked this out in a few minutes, so hopefully there aren't any bugs (but use at your own risk).

```
# Import data
x <- structure(list(contestant = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), judge = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), rating = c(83.03, 67.15, 72.05, 86.95, 44, 96.5, 
89.9, 84.6, 93.3, 65.15, 88.5, 85.36, 78.95, 88, 52.45, 90.5, 
89.85, 85, 94.1, 96.05)), .Names = c("contestant", "judge", "rating"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

> # Mean: Judge's Mean rating - i.e., bias
round(tapply(x$rating, x$judge, function(X) mean(X)), 1)
   1    2    3    4    5 
89.6 83.1 80.2 90.6 64.4
```

This shows that judge 5 is harsh and perhaps also that judge 1 and 4 maybe too lenient.

```
> # SD: Judge's SD rating i.e., excessive or insufficient variability in ratings
round(tapply(x$rating, x$judge, function(X) sd(X)), 1)
   1    2    3    4    5 
 5.6 10.8  6.1  3.6 22.8
```

This shows that judge 5 is vastly more variable, but equally the other judges vary in their variability quite a lot also.

```
> # Correlation
judgecor <- list()
for (i in unique(x$judge)) {
      contestant_mean <- tapply(
      x[x$judge != i, "rating"], x[x$judge != i, "contestant"], 
      function(X) mean(X))
    judgecor[[as.character(i)]] <- cor(x[x$judge == i, "rating"], contestant_mean)
}
round(unlist(judgecor), 2)
   1    2    3    4    5 
0.70 0.84 0.96 0.95 0.73
```

Judge 1 and 5 are less consistent with the other judges.

```
> # Residuals
fit <- lm(rating~factor(judge)+factor(contestant), x)
xres <- data.frame(x, res=residuals(fit))
xres$absres <- abs(xres$res)

# Overview of problematic ratings
head(xres[order(xres$absres, decreasing=TRUE), ], 5)

   contestant judge rating    res absres
20          4     5  96.05 22.107 22.107
5           1     5  44.00 -9.479  9.479
15          3     5  52.45 -9.045  9.045
16          4     1  90.50 -8.663  8.663
4           1     4  86.95  7.296  7.296
```

This shows the largest five absolute residuals in ratings after taking out mean contestant and mean rater effects.
It shows clearly that the rating by judge 5 on contestant 4 was an extreme outlier, relative to the other residuals.

Answer (score 2):

You could measure agreement in ratings across judges with [inter-rater reliability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-rater_reliability) statistics. This would tell you whether the judging of contestants is consistent across judges.

There may be a more sophisticated way of doing this, but I might naively try dropping out each of the five judges individually looking at how the reliability changes.

But with such a small sample, I don't think you'll get particularly strong answers whatever you do.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to demonstrate bias, but you can try to establish whether the 96.05 is an outlier using Dixon's Test for Outliers.  If these judges went on to judge these same contestants on another task/domain, you could test for the replicability of this unusual result for Judge 5 and Contestant 4.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of this as a test of variances. Judge 5's scores will get more weight because the variability of the scores is higher.

This test would be for the equality of two variances. It's in most intro stat books, and even in Excel, which provides the following results for judge 5 versus judge 1-4

F-Test Two-Sample for Variances

```
Variable 1  Variable 2
```

Mean    64.4125 85.85875

Variance    520.415625  60.13891833

Observations    4   16

df  3   15

F   8.653558119

P(F<=f) one-tail    0.001424952

F Critical one-tail 3.287382105

This does show judge 5 is significantly more variable than the other judges, but frankly I would be careful of a result like this because of the amount of "fishing" involved. You're looking at this after-the-fact, with several possible hypotheses available (just to start, there are equivalent tests of judge 1 against 2,3,4,5, judge 2 against 1,3,4,5, etc.)

It's also possible that even if you are observing something, it might not be what you think. You might not be observing bias for/against contestants for a consistent tendency to view things in a different way -- sort of like umpires being willing to call a high strike in American baseball, with various pitchers tending to use/not use a high strike.

If you had more contest results, you could compare judge 5 (and others) versus some overall norm. That gets around the fact that with a small sample of judges and ratings (and a posthoc analysis!) you can't really get above the suspicion level.